# Can I use .handlebars files with Meteor?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

For the sake of clarity, and because SublimeText isn't bright enough to know the difference between lots of different flavors of ".html", I thought about using .handlebars as the extension to my handlebars-templated files. Meteor seems to only accept files with with .html extension, and I'm wondering if there's a way I can get it to accept .handlebars files too. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps it would be possible to use `.handlebars.html` extension and make Sublime recognize that?

Comment: That's a really good plan, Hubert. I made a github issue for it: https://github.com/daaain/Handlebars/issues/40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment left by Hubert OG was the simplest solution. Use `.handlebars.html` files. [The SublimeText plugin for handlebars now recognizes that file extension too.](https://github.com/daaain/Handlebars/commit/5bae3f80dca9e6e247368bc55f32f0373ba1e07e)

Answer (score 1):

This may be more complicated than you'd like, but one way you can accomplish this is by making your own version of the [`templating`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/templating) package.

1. make a copy of the subtree,
2. rename the package,
3. edit [`plugin/compile-templates.js`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/templating/plugin/compile-templates.js) and at the bottom in the call to `registerSourceHandler`, replace `"html"` with `"handlebars"`.
4. put your new package into your project's `packages` and add it using `meteor add yourpackagename`.